# How do I fix my Intel Graphics Update Tool?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, updates, graphics, intel-graphics

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop, and it has an Intel graphics card.  I realized my drivers were out of date, so I went to https://01.org/linuxgraphics/ and downloaded `intel-graphics-update-tool_2.0.2_amd64.deb` and installed it via `dpkg`.  When I run the tool however, it works fine until it comes to the point where it installs the updates.  It gives this error:

```
Error running transaction: 
GDBus.Error:org.debian.apt.TransactionFailed: error-dep-resolution-
failed: The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libgles1-mesa: Depends: libglapi-mesa (= 12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) but 
17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 is to be installed
```

I checked, and I do have the latest version of `libglapi-mesa`.  Version `17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.1`

What do I do about this?

Comment: Did you follow the instructions about signatures? Please [edit] and post the results of `sudo apt update`.

Comment: @MichaelBay no I didn't.  What instructions?

Comment: The instructions in the downloads page: Signatures - Ubuntu* (https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-update-tool-linux-os-v2.0.2)

Comment: @MichaelBay I just followed the instructions and added the GPG key, but I still get the same error when the update tool is run.

Comment: Check the answer. Please note it only corrects the error induced by the incorrect use of the Intel tool. It doesn't correct other software source errors you may have had previously. And once added (the keys) you **don't need to run the tool again**, just update the system. The tool is just a fancy GUI that, in the background, adds the PPA (- key) and runs sudo apt update / upgrade. That's ALL it does and generally you don't need it because all Intel provides are minor updates. If any *relevant* update is needed it will be added to the official Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: @MichaelBay Thanks so much!  You've been a big help. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Intel® Graphics Update Tool adds the Intel's PPA. As mentioned [here](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-update-tool-linux-os-v2.0.2), *in order to "trust" the Intel® Graphics Update Tool for Linux OS, you will need to add keys to Ubuntu's software package manager ("apt")*. Ideally this should be done before *running for the first time or upgrading from an earlier release*. But can be done now and should work for the purpose if there are no other issues with your software sources.

In terminal please run the following commands:

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg-4 -O - | \
sudo apt-key add -
```

Then the app itself is no longer needed. Do a full update and the new versions, if any, will be downloaded and installed:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks!  That works great.  Except for one thing.  What does this mean? `W: https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/16.04/main/dists/xenial/InRelease: Signature by key 09D6EF97BFB38E916EF060E756A3DEF863961D39 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
`

Comment: It means exactly what it says and it's not a big deal (it doesn't prevent the update) and nothing that can be "solved" from the users side. Some time ago, Debian/Ubuntu started strongly recommending the use of stronger algorithms but many third party repositories "didn't get the memo" (or did and ignored it). Only the maintainers (Intel in this case) can improve it.